# Redirect route in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, meteor, handlebars.js

So I want to create a bit.ly type site in meteor.js.  I can't figure out how to redirect off page.  I used backbone.js for the routes, which are working.  Ideally it would grab the link from the database, create the link and redirect to it.  I tried window.location but that doesn't work properly
js file:

```
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "" : "main",
        "/" : "main",
        "help" : "help",
        'help/' : "help",
      },
      main: function() {
        Session.set('currentPage', 'homePage');
      },
      help: function() {
        Session.set('currentPage', 'helpPage');
      }
    });
    var app = new Router;
    Meteor.startup(function () {
      Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    });
    Template.home.homePage = function(){
      return Session.get("currentPage") == 'homePage';
    };
    Template.help.helpPage = function(){
      return Session.get("currentPage") == 'helpPage';
      //I want to do a redirect here somewhere:
      //window.location = 'http://google.com';
    };
  }
```

html:

```
<head>
  <title>My app name</title>
</head>

<body>
 {{> home}}
 {{> help}}
</body>

<template name="home">
    {{#if homePage}}
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="help">
    {{#if helpPage}}
        <h1>Help Page</h1>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to an external url. You can overide the router navigate

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
 var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
 routes: {
  "" : "main",
  "help" : "help",
  'about' : "about",
 },
 navigate: function (url) { window.location = url; },
 main: function() {
  Session.set('currentPage', 'homePage');
 },
 help: function() {
  Session.set('currentPage', 'helpPage');
 },
 about: function() {
  Session.set('currentPage', 'about');
 }
});

var app;
Meteor.startup(function () {
 app = new Router;
 Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
Template.content.homePage = function(){
 return Session.get("currentPage") == 'homePage';
};
Template.content.helpPage = function(){
 return Session.get("currentPage") == 'helpPage';
};
Template.content.aboutPage = function(){
 return Session.get("currentPage") == 'about';
};

//I will add a helper below that will redirect to google everytime about link is     clicked. Open console to see message logged before redirect

Template.about.rendered = function(){
 console.log('About is about to be rendered but wait..... we redirect to google.com');
 app.navigate('http://google.com');
};
```

Comment: If you do not wish to override navigate, then simply use this `window.location.href = 'http://google.com';`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/help', trueorfalse);
```

true if you want to run the router method that updates the session variable

Comment: Can you expand upon that, I'm fairly new to meteor/backbone.  Maybe a redirect example?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your html template to help explain how to redirect using Backbone.history.navigate. I added two additional templates called content and about and 3 static links directing to three routes home, help and about. content depends on what our template helpers homePage, helpPage or aboutPage return

```
<head>
 <title>My app name</title>
</head>

<body>
 <a href='/'>Home</a>
 <a href='/help'>Help</a>
 <a href='/about'>About</a>
 {{> content}}
</body>

<template name='content'>
{{#if homePage}}
    {{> home}}
{{/if}}

{{#if helpPage}}
    {{> help}}
{{/if}}

{{#if aboutPage}}
    {{> about}}
{{/if}}
</template>

<template name="home">
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
</template>

<template name="help">
    <h1>Help Page</h1>
</template>

<template name="about">
    <h1>About Page</h1>
</template>
```

JS is now

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "" : "main",
    "help" : "help",
    'about' : "about",
  },
  main: function() {
    Session.set('currentPage', 'homePage');
  },
  help: function() {
    Session.set('currentPage', 'helpPage');
  },
  about: function() {
    Session.set('currentPage', 'about');
  }
});

Meteor.startup(function () {
  var app = new Router;
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
Template.content.homePage = function(){
  return Session.get("currentPage") == 'homePage';
};
Template.content.helpPage = function(){
  return Session.get("currentPage") == 'helpPage';
 };
Template.content.aboutPage = function(){
  return Session.get("currentPage") == 'about';
};

//I will add a helper below that will redirect to homePage everytime about link is clicked. Open console to see message logged before redirect

Template.about.rendered = function(){
  console.log('About is about to be rendered but wait..... we redirect to home');
  Backbone.history.navigate( "/", true);
};
}
```

Comment: This works, but not when I try to direct it offsite. `Backbone.history.navigate( "http://google.com", true);` Goes to: `localhost:3000/http://google.com`. How would you navigate to a different domain?

Comment: I am going to add another answer